# Scroll does not work on IOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, less

I have a div -200% absolute and when i click, that div comes bottom 0 and generate an iframe off my product page, but when i access that iframe on IOS devices, this not allow me to scroll.

I tried this on Safari and Google Chrome.

CSS:

```
.our-category {
  width: 100%;
}

.our-category .liso-ja {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

.myProduct {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -200%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  display: none;
}

.myProduct iframe {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="our-category">
    <div class="liso-ja show">
        <div class="product dir-esq">
            <div>
                <h2>Tratamento Matizador</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form><button class="buy weltpixel-quickview weltpixel_quickview_button_v2" title="Comprar!" type="button" data-quickview-url="http://192.168.13.42/Procfit-Institucional/weltpixel_quickview/catalog_product/view/id/2"> comprar matizador </button></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="produtoAjax" class="myProduct" style="display: block; bottom: 0px;">
        <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;overflow-y: scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" src="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On iOS, you made want to add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to your scroll container. By default, Safari will not smoothly scroll these elements.

Comment: Shows a message "Invalid property value"